# missing C libraries errors when running gedit

Tags: 16.04, gedit, c++, libraries, glibc

I appended this to the end of `~/.bashrc`

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/sys/os/glnxa64:

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

This picture says it all. Could anyone tell me how to fix this please?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a wrong `ldconfig` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. You could run `ldconfig -p | grep -i matlab` to check if it is related to ldconfig or check any profile or bashrc files that might set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Maybe you can remember how you configured matlab...and reverse that?

Comment: @Thomas. Yes I did set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable in `.bashrc` because I need to use Matlab Compiler SDK to run Matlab compiled-to-jar functions in Java. After the installation of Matlab SDK, it told me to append 3 paths `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, that is why I did it.

Comment: Could you post how exaclty the export of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` looks like? It seems this is the source of your problem.

Comment: @Thomas please see my edit

Comment: If I removed the lines tthat sets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable from `/.bashrc`, it works again. look like when I set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable, Linux is trying to use the `libstdc++.so.6` from Matlab under `/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/sys/os/glnxa64` directory and it tries to load another c++ file that does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the export of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your `.bashrc`, you are adding a new search path for libraries that has precedence.

The problem now is that `gedit` also expects the library `libstdc++.so.6` which is picked up in the Matlab install directory. Obviously the library has the same name, but does not match to the `gedit` expected one.

To get rid of your problem, you should remove that Matlab specific stuff from your `.bashrc` and maybe write a wrapper script to start Matlab:

```
$ cat matlab.script
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/sys/os/glnxa64:
<path-to-matlab-binary>
```

As you mentioned to use SDK, not sure if you need that in `bash` you only should load the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for Matlab when needed. You also might want to have a look at `environment-modules` which is a helper programm to configure different development tools and their needed pathes and keep up with the mess.

Comment: I don't specifically require to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `~/.bashrc`. Because I am writing an application in Java which calls some functions written in Matlab language, and these functions were compiled to jars. And to be able to integrate Matlab into Java that way, I need to install Matlab Compiler SDK, and like I said, it required me to append 3 paths to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable. But when I run my Java app, it still says the file `libmwmclmcrrt.so.9.0.1` is not found on `java.library.path` even though this file is in `/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/runtime/glnxa64`